# Syntax difference of priority_queue implementing min heap with descending sort of vector

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, priority-queue

The syntax to implement min-heap using priority_queue STL is

`std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int> > my_min_heap;`

whereas, the syntax of implementing a `sort()` for vector in descending order is

`sort(a.begin(), a.end(), greater<int>());`

My question is sort uses **()** after greater but priority_queue does not. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int> > my_min_heap;
```

`std::greater<int>` is a template parameter, note that it is inside `<>`. It  is a type. On the other hand, here

```
sort(a.begin(), a.end(), greater<int>());
```

an instance of that type is created and passed to `sort`. Also `sort` has a template parameter for the comparator, but it is deduced from the argument (to be of type `std::greater<int>`), so there is no need to specify it explicitly.

More specifically `std::greater<int>` is a functor ie a type that has an overload for the function call operator. To create an instance and use that to compare two `int`s you could write:

```
bool x = std::greater<int>()(5,3);
         /*  the type   */
                        // ^ call constructor
                          // ^ call the objects operator()
```

However, typically the same function object is reused for many comparisons, as is the case with `std::sort`.